# jsp page being overwritten by JSON data being sent from Servlet

Tags: json, jsp, servlets

I am trying to send JSON data to my JSP page from a servlet.
AS soon as I run the JSP, the whole of JSP gets overwritten by the JSON content. why is this happening? This is part of my JSP page.

```
    <%@ page import="java.util.ArrayList" %>
    <head>
    <script>
    function populateTypeOfWork(workType) {
        var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
            if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
                var work = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
                workType.options.length = 0;
                for (i = 0; i < work.length; i++) {
                    createOption(workType, workDesc[i], workDesc[i]);
                }
            }
            xhttp.open("GET", "ServletRequest", true);
            xhttp.send();
        }
    }
    function createOption(dropdown, text, value) {
        var x = document.createElement('option');
        x.value = value;
        x.text = text;
        dropdown.options.add(x);
    }
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <label>Work Category **</label>
  <select id="workCategory" 
   onchange="populateTypeOfWork(document.getElementById('workTypeDesc1'))" 
   size=1
    style="width:95%;" required>
  <option value="" selected>Select A Work Category</option>
   <% ArrayList workCategory = (ArrayList) 
 request.getAttribute("workCategory");
    for (int i = 0; i < workCategory.size(); i++) {
%>
<option value="<%=workCategory.get(i)%>"><%=workCategory.get(i)%>
</option>
<% } %>
</select>&nbsp;<br>

<label>Type Of Work **</label>
<select id="workTypeDesc1" size=1 style="width:95%;" required>
<option value="" selected>Type of Work</option>
</select>
</body>
</html>
```

Servlet

```
    String json = new Gson().toJson(arraylistvar);
    res.setContentType("application/json");
    PrintWriter pw = res.getWriter();
    pw.flush();
    pw.close();
    req.setAttribute("viewURL","/page1.jsp");
```

Why does stackoverflow keep asking me to add more details? because its mostly code..?? why should I fill this post unnecessaily?

Answer (score 0):

There are two problems I can see with the current code: (1) you are referencing a non-existent variable workDesc; it appears you should reference the variable named work instead, and (b) the code that sends the AJAX request is inside the onreadystatechange() event handler, when it should actually execute right after the event handler is set. Here is the revised code snippet:

```
xhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
        var work = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
        workType.options.length = 0;
        for (i = 0; i < work.length; i++) {
            createOption(workType, work[i], work[i]);
        }
    }
}
xhttp.open("GET", "ServletRequest", true);
xhttp.send();
```

Comment: ohh ya sorry about workDesc. What do you mean the code should execute right after the event handler is set? how do I go about that? btw I dont think its a problem from the jsp side because if I comment out the AJAX code, still the whole of JSP gets overwritten by the JSON array.

Comment: I fixed my revised code snippet; take note of where the calls to open() and send() are.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. I figured another issue. My JSP is in projWebApp/proj1/Mypage.jsp . Servlet is in projWebApp//WEB-INF/classes/servlet/ServletRequest.java . What should be the servlet's path in xhttp.open("....")?

Comment: The file under WEB-INF/classes should be a \*.class file, not a \*.java file (\*.class files are compiled from \*.java files.) The request path can be set in the web.xml file, or with recent versions of Java Servlets, can be specified by an annotation of the ServletRequest class directly in ServletRequest.java. To know how to help further I would need to know what IDE (integrated development environment) you are using, if any, and how you are building your application from its source code.

Comment: I strongly recommend this page for further reading: https://stackoverflow.com/tags/servlets/info

Comment: Well, these are .java . This application has been passed onto me through somebody else, so really can't say why do we have java files in classes folder. I am using Intellij and Ant quuckbuild.

Comment: It should be a simple matter of moving the ServletRequest.java file to a different folder, probably named "src". I have not used IntelliJ before; perhaps someone who has will chime in and provide more help.

Comment: When you have moved the .java file to the right place, try adding this line above the "public class ServletRequest" line in it: 
@WebServlet("/ServletRequest"). This will map the servlet to the path "/ServletRequest".

Comment: Well, thanks for your input. This is a big application, some other people also using the same java, jsp files so unfortunately cant change its location folder.

Answer (score -1):

This might be due to how the request is being made from your web page. You should be using an AJAX call; make sure you are not submitting an ordinary form or changing the URL of the page within your JavaScript.